# Syntax for accessing struct property with enum type in JSON model

Tags: json, swift, syntax, model

I am trying to access a url string contained within some JSON data.

The string is contained within the "urls" array with type "detail" as can be seen below.

[JSON DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyucZ.png)

I used [quicktype](https://quicktype.io) to construct my model as below:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let thumbnail: Thumbnail
    let urls: [URLElement]


}

    struct Thumbnail: Codable {
        let path: String
        let thumbnailExtension: Extension

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case path
            case thumbnailExtension = "extension"
        }
    }

    enum Extension: String, Codable {
    case jpg = "jpg"
}

struct URLElement: Codable {
    let type: URLType
    let url: String
    }

    enum URLType: String, Codable {
        case comiclink = "comiclink"
        case detail = "detail"
        case wiki = "wiki"
    }
```

I have tried accessing it by declaring it like so...

```
var urlelement: URLElement!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let detailurl = urlelement.url
        print(detailurl)
```

... but it always returns an empty string.  Any suggestions will be most welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: can you please give the json

Comment: is this is your complete code, where are you downloading the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Download the JSON then user `JSONDecoder`

let url = URL(string: "your url")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

```
if let error = error {
    print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
}

guard let data = data else { return }

do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    // use this

    response?.data.results.forEach({ (rsl) in
        rsl.urls.forEach({ (element) in
            print(element.type, element.url)
        })
    })

    // or this one

    for rsl in response!.data.results {
        for element in rsl.urls {
            print(element.type, element.url)
        }
    }
} catch let error {
    print("error while decoding the json \(error.localizedDescription)")

}

}.resume()
```

Comment: Awesome! I had already written out the above code but it was this line I needed: 

print(response.data.results[0].urls[0].url)

Now, if the line prints out the first url of type detail in the array, how would i print out every url?

Here is the link to the raw JSON http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=ff3d4847092294acc724123682af904b&hash=412b0d63f1d175474216fadfcc4e4fed&limit=25&orderBy=-modified

Comment: updated the answer, if the answer was acceptable please accept the answer

Comment: try this playground 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zj3xmh5znotah7s/SamplePlayground.playground.zip?dl=0